# Can't compile and run minisat+ sat solver

Tags: c, linux, compilation, cc

I use one of the Cent0S machines in my university's department.Note that i don't have permissions to use the system i use as root.I downloaded the [minisat+zip file](http://minisat.se/MiniSat+.html)

I extracted the zip.According to install file i run

> make rx

but i have the following result:

```
Makefile:96: depend.mak: No such file or directory
Making dependencies...
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ./Main.h:23,
                 from <command-line>:0:
ADTs/Int.h:101:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [depend.mak] Error 1
```

I also downloaded minisat+ from [github](https://github.com/niklasso/minisatp).

I run it using

> make

and

> make install

but i still have errors.
Someone told me that i need to install gmp and gmp-devel?Is that right?

Something that might help:I am not sure if i have password as a root user because i work on my university's labs.

Does anyone how to run minisat+ properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like minisat depends on the [GNU MP Bignum library (gmp)](http://gmplib.org/). Do you have libgmp installed on your system?

---

### Update: Installing libraries on a System you don't have root access to

Since you're on a university machine without root-access, you have a couple of options:

1. Ask some IT guy from the university staff to install libgmp on the machine for you. This might be the easiest approach depending on how complaisant the sysadmins are.
2. Over on [Superuser is a thread discussing how to install packages a normal user](https://superuser.com/questions/198674/using-yum-to-install-packages-for-my-user-only). After that you still have to add the library search path (using the `-L` switch) to the `CFLAGS` in the Makefile of the minisat package.
3. You could build libgmp manually like this: 
   When you're done, you also have to modify the minisat-Makefile just like with option #2
   .

   ```
   $ cd 
   $ mkdir opt/gmp

   $ wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-5.1.2.tar.bz2
   $ tar -xjvf gmp-5.1.2.tar.bz2

   $ cd gmp-5.1.2

   $ ./configure --prefix=~/opt/gmp/ &&
   $ make &&
   // this will install libgmp into /home/your-login/opt/gmp/
   $ make install
   ```

Comment: How can i see if i have libgmp installed on my system?

Comment: @Dchris depends. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Dchris I never used CentOS, but you should be able to install it by typing `yum install gmp` into a console. Although you might not have enough privileges on a university machine

Comment: I can't install libgmp because i don't have privileges for being root